# gulp-open not working after createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am using gulp, gulp-eslint and gulp-open to create a report of ESLint results.
The linting and file writing part works correctly, but the task to open the file I wrote my report in, does not.

```
gulp.task('LintAll_Report_After', ['LintAll'], function () {
    gulp.src('./_reports/eslint-html-result.html').pipe(open());
});

gulp.task('LintAll_Report', function () {
    gulp.src('./_reports/eslint-html-result.html').pipe(open());
});

gulp.task('LintAll', function () {
    gulp.src('./_reports/eslint-html-result.html').pipe(open());
    var stream = gulp.src(filesToLintGlob)
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format('html', fs.createWriteStream('./_reports/eslint-html-result.html')));
    //stream.on('finish', function () {
    //    console.log('finished');
    //    stream.end();
    //    setTimeout(function () {
    //        gulp.src('./_reports/eslint-html-result.html').pipe(open());
    //    }, 10000);
    //});
    return stream;
});
```

- LintAll lints my files, then writes the results into an html file.
- LintAll_Report opens my report in the browser.
- LintAll_Report_After supposedly opens my report after completing the LintAll task.

LintAll works fine.The problem is with the report opening: LintAll_Report works, if called by itself... But LintAll_Report_After does not work. There are no errors, in the Task Runner Explorer console I even see the line `[13:40:17] Opening C:\GITDEV\stiletto-online\_reports\eslint-html-result.html using the default OS app` just like as with LintAll_Report, but the file isn't opened in the browser.

Any idea why this could be happening?
I even tried opening the file by binding to an event, but that wasn't successful either - I get the message that it's opening the file, but nothing happens. This is the commented part. Even tried with or without a setTimeout, and both with/without calling stream.end()

My first guess was it wouldn't open the file because it did not really finish writing and something went wrong, but that was disproved with event binding and timeout. Now I'm really clueless

EDIT: I forgot to add: the inital call to open in LintAll does not work either. Removing the call does not change the results.

EDIT2: I just tried installing a different version of NodeJS and set up VS so that it would use my customised version - but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work, but I'm not satisfied.

By specifying the Task Runner Explorer bindings at the top of the file with LintAll first and LintAll_Report later, it seems to be working

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='LintAll, LintAll_Report' />
```

But this does not feel like the right way to do this, if anybody has a better answer I would be glad to hear it.